# WebFlux: how to deserialize interface parameter of a Controller?

Tags: jackson, spring-webflux

I am using Spring Webflux and I need to deserialize an Interface object passed as the parameter of a `Restcontroller`.

Please note the I am not allowed to edit the interface in any way, since it is from another library. I am using [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) here to reduce boilerplate code.

**This is the interface**

```
public interface MyInterface {
    String getField();
    void setField(String field);
}
```

**with the corresponding implementation**

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface {
    private String field;
}
```

**and the Rest controller**

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @PostMapping("/interface/test")
    public String test(@RequestBody MyInterface myInterface){
        return myInterface.toString();
    }
}
```

In this example I am using this JSON of the MyInterface:

```
{
    "field":"Test interface field"
}
```

Now, if I try to call the endpoint as it is with the above JSON,
I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.core.codec.CodecException: Type definition error: [simple type, class project.dto.model.MyInterface]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `project.dto.model.MyInterface` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (io.netty.buffer.ByteBufInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
```

What I did was to implement a **custom JsonDeserializer**

```
public class MyInterfaceDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<MyInterface> {
    @Override
    public MyInterface deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return jsonParser.readValueAs(MyInterfaceImpl.class);
    }
}
```

and provide it as a **Module**:

```
@Configuration
public class Jacksonconfiguration {

    @Bean
    Module myInterfaceDeserializerModule(){
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addDeserializer(MyInterface.class, new MyInterfaceDeserializer());
        return module;
    }
}
```

However the module does not seem to get auto registered as documented and the deserialization error still remains.
How can I make the MyInterface to automatically get deserialized from the controller parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a pre-configured objectMapper, you can use CommandLineRunner to add module:

```
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration implements CommandLineRunner {
    
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    
    public JacksonConfiguration(final ObjectMapper objectMapper ) {
            this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run(final String... args ) {
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addDeserializer( MyInterface.class, new MyInterfaceDeserializer() );
        objectMapper.registerModule( module );
    }
}
```